How to pause ios app's video playing in Picture in Picture (PIP) when user locks the iPhone?
I am have implemented PIP in my app. When user goes to background while video was playing. App opens PIP and everything works fine. But when user locks the device , PIP is not stopping/Pausing the video.
Is there a way I can pause the Video when user locks the device?
